# About JAVA multithreading : How to create a process with extends Thread and implement Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

When I was reading the book "Thinking in JAVA", I found a question about JAVA multithreading.

```
    class ThreadMethod {
    private int countdown = 5;
    private Thread t;
    private String name;

    public ThreadMethod(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void runTask() {
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(name) {
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println(this);
                        if (--countdown == 0) return;
                        try {
                            sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            System.out.println("interrupted");
                        }
                    }
                }

                public String toString() {
                    return getName() + ": " + countdown;
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    }
}

public class ThreadVarations{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        new ThreadMethod("ThreadMethod").runTask();
    }
}
```

The class ThreadMethod doesn't `extends Thread` and `implements Runnable`. So the class how to create a process?

Comment: Did you skip chapter about anonymous classes? Take a look at `new Thread(name) { public void run() { ... } }`.

Comment: I don't know how to describe my mood. This is a very low-level error. In fact, when I asked the question, I realized that I was wrong. I miss the "Thread t private".

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate a new Thread with a given class that implements Runnable and call start on it, the method `run()` would be called in the other thread.

```
new Thread(new ThreadMethod).start();
```